# My app get force closes when there is a fall in Internet connection-Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-emulator

My app get force closes when  there is a fall in Internet connection.
I have Checked the status of internet connection in splashscreen by this method and it works fine.The thing is when my app runs smooth if there is a failure in Internet connection it crashes the whole application(Force Close)..How to overcome this one

public boolean isNetworkAvailable()

```
{
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo networkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected())
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

1 Activity:
vec = WSSender.getname(letter, "0", "100",dictionary);

Webservice Activity:

```
   public static Vector getname(String str,String str1, String str2, String str3) throws IOException, Exception
   {

           SoapObject request = new SoapObject(WSConstants.NAMESPACE, WSConstants.METHOD_NAME);
           request.addProperty("letter",str);
           request.addProperty("start", str1);
           request.addProperty("end", str2);
           request.addProperty("tableName",str3);
           SoapObject resultObject = send(request,WSConstants.SOAP_ACTION );
           //String prelist = resultObject.toString();
           Vector preList = WSResponseParser.parseDetailforhn(resultObject);
           return preList;
   }
```

Comment: upload the stack trace .

Comment: Losing connectivity won't kill your app unless the code is in the middle of doing something and it isn't handling the loss of connection correctly. Post your logcat to show the exception being thrown and the code where it is happening.

Comment: in your application if you call an http service at the same time before the completion of the call if the net connection fails this can happen, you can check fro net connection first and then place the request and also do put exception handlers to handle the exceptions properly

Answer (score 0):

***Try this:***

```
hello.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View paramView) {
        net = isOnline();
        Toast.makeText(SampleActivity.this, "Hello", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});

private boolean isOnline() {
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

***Add permission in the manifest:***

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Comment: Nitesh, pankaj: I did the same instead toast i used alert,if wifi is not connected it works fine man and gives me alert but if there is a internet connection and my app runs gud,someone switch off the wifi it get force close ehile fetching the data from webservice

Answer (score 0):

```
You have to perform below check not only in the splash screen but all the places in the appp where internet related tasks are done i.e date upload or download

 //decleration
boolean net;

//onCreate
net = isOnline();
if (net == true)
{
//perform internet related tasks in the app
}

//function
public boolean isOnline() {
        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo activeNetworkInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        return activeNetworkInfo != null;

        // return cm.getActiveNetworkInfo().isConnected();

    }
```

Comment: Myself using webservice and it fetches the data from internet and my webservice methods are in another class.is it possible to check when i call a method of another activity.

Comment: At the place where you call the method perform the above check which I suggested.